# mapping and filtering an array of objects with key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects for users:

```
const users = [
    0: {
        name: "John",
        email: "jsmith@gmail.com"
    },
    1: {
        name: "Bob",
        email: "bsmith@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

A useState that controls which user id is selected.

```
const [id, setId] = useState("1");
```

For example I have a default state set to id=1

I am trying to map and filter through the array of objects above to get the name, and email based on the id inside the array for the object.

Here is the code of what I am trying to do, but it doesn't seem to get the data from array of objects.

```
{Object.keys(users).filter((user) => user.id === id).map((user, index) => {
    const userDetails = users[user]
    return (
        <div className="profile" key={index}>
            <h1>{userDetails.name}</h1>
            <h1>{userDetails.email}</h1>
        </div>
    );
})}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`users` is an array of objects. So just use index without filter or map:

```
const userDetails = users[id]
return (
    <div className="profile">
        <h1>{userDetails.name}</h1>
        <h1>{userDetails.email}</h1>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the accepted answer:

Even if `users` *was* an object, `Object.keys(users).filter((user) => user.id === id).map()` is redundant if you're only interested in a single user. You can just access the `users` object directly by the selected id as a key.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const users = {
  0: {
    name: "John",
    email: "jsmith@gmail.com"
  },
  1: {
    name: "Bob",
    email: "bsmith@gmail.com"
  },
  2: {
    name: "Jill",
    email: "jjones@gmail.com"
  },
  3: {
    name: "Joan",
    email: "jjohnson@gmail.com"
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId] = useState("0");
  return (
    <>
      <div className="profile">
        <h1>{users[selectedUserId].name}</h1>
        <h1>{users[selectedUserId].email}</h1>
      </div>
      <label>
        selected user id:
        <input
          type="number"
          min={0}
          max={Object.keys(users).length - 1}
          value={selectedUserId}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSelectedUserId(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </label>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit unruffled-minsky-pgjzh]

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your users declaration is wrong. Either change it to an array or an object. Now its a mix of both in wrong syntax.

[The following code is a workable sample.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r5ad4g)

```
export default function App() {
 const [id, setId] = useState("1");

 const users = {
  0: {
      name: "John",
      email: "jsmith@gmail.com"
  },
  1: {
      name: "Bob",
      email: "bsmith@gmail.com"
  }
 }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

      {!!users[id] && <div className="profile">
                        <h1>{ users[id].name}</h1>
                        <h1>{users[id].email}</h1>
                      </div>
      }
   
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The syntax is not wrong, it's just what display console.log inside your browser

Comment: I mean the users object posted by the author instead of the one posted by me. @NicolasMenettrier

Comment: yes but i'm quite sure he just copy pasted a console log result inside the browser (it show exactly the same output)

Comment: Right, his users declaration resembles the one in chrome console. @NicolasMenettrier